# Putting in an SD card made my Zedge ringtones unusable and I can't access the pet shop app etc.,

Tags: applications, sd-card, ringtone, t-mobile

I don't have an Android, but my girlfriend said she needed an SD card, so I got her one. She put it in her phone, it just said 'setting up SD card' and she didn't have to do anything else.

It made her ringtones for specific callers stop working. Then it stopped even showing her downloaded ringtones in Zedge and started using a 'default' ringtone which is one she had never heard, her phone is a T-Mobile Touch and its default ringtone is the T-Mobile theme, not the one that is playing.

She has also been using a pet shop game on her phone for about 2 years and now she can't use it. It will just say the app isn't installed. Going into the application manager, I can see that there is a file with the word 'petshop' in it saying it is on the SD card, the file and the other 2 (one is eBay app) are grayed out.

The whole purpose of the SD card was so that she could move all of her pictures of our son onto it in order to have them printed out or to move them to a new phone when she gets one. I don't honestly even know how to do that.

Comment: Was the SD card a replacement for a smaller one she had in the device before?

Comment: It wasn't a replacement. It was the first one ever used in the device I think. It was a Sandisk 8GB.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the trouble is you've replaced the existing SD card without having copied the data. With apps installed on the (original) SD card, those are naturally "gone" as soon as you've popped it out – and did not "magically transfer" to the new card.

What you'd have to do is to first copy everything from the original card to the new one – including the "hidden directories". For how to do that, you might wish to consult [How do I switch my Android device's SD card without causing problems?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17402/16575)

Comment: It wasn't a replacement card. There was no SD card in the phone when this one was put in and the apps/ringtones were working properly from the internal memory.

I haven't owned an android before, but I'm pretty good with PC's and technology in general and I am baffled by what the SD card did to her phone. Thank you for your help so far, Izzy. I appreciate the responses!

Comment: Yuck. I've missed 3 chars of your comment on the question: "True. I was in a hurry before work. It was***n't*** a replacement." Sorry for that! So I'm baffled now: what happens if the card is removed? Do the apps show up again?